# Horizontally stacking divs in same order with bootstrap grid system when div order alternates

Tags: html, css

I have a Bootstrap (v4.1.3) grid system where I have text and an image in a 50/50 column orientation. Every alternating row reverses the order of the text/img for viewing aesthetics. So I'll have the below on a normal desktop view:

```
    [Text]    [Img]
    [Img]     [Text]
    etc...
```

I want it so that when the resolution is small enough, it stacks the divs vertically so that it's similar to this:

```
    [Img]
    [Text]
    [Img]
    [Text]
```

But what I'm actually getting is:

```
    [Text]
    [Img]
    [Img]
    [Text]
```

My grid set up is similar to the below. This gives me the 50/50 on desktop and horizonal stacked on mobile, but how do I ensure that the img div is always first, then the text div?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-text-col">
            Text Content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-img-col">
            Image Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-img-col">
            Image Content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-text-col">
            Text Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit** - This is what I ended up doing:

```
@media screen and (max-width:576px) {
    .container {
        .row .my-img-col {
            order: 1;
        }

        .row .my-text-col {
            order: 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: What version of BS?

Comment: @TravisActon Bootstrap v4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a repeating pattern, ou will need to create an extra mediaquerie that match with the col-sm rule :

example

```css
@media screen and (max-width:576px) {/* make sure you did not modify the sm brakpoint in your bootstrap configuration , else update this mediaquerie to the same breakpoint value */
  .row:nth-child(odd) .col-sm:nth-child(1) {order:2;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-text-col">
            Text Content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-img-col">
            Image Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-img-col">
            Image Content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-text-col">
            Text Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

With the latest version of bootstrap, order class do have the break point rules option

it could be :

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-text-col">
            Text Content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-img-col">
            Image Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-img-col  order-2 order-sm-1 ">
            Image Content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-text-col  order-sm-2">
            Text Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will need to add the class to each rows supposed to reorder . if you need a repeating pattern, nth-child(n) option might be easier to handle.

Comment: I didn't actually need to use nth-child, I just ended up explicitly setting the orders. You can see my edit for what I mean.

Comment: @test hmm time to switch off, i did not noticed the specific text and image class ... glad the hint was good enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are able to change the order of columns for different view ports using `order-*` class.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-text-col order-1">
        Text Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-img-col order-2">
        Image Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-img-col order-12 order-sm-1">
        Image Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-xs-12 my-text-col order-2">
        Text Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Please read more about it here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering