# Bootstrap order changes depending if displayed as 1 or 2 column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a webpage which displays two columns of cards, unless screen width gets smaller then **md** size. My problem is that I want the most important items to appear higher up the page, so I put important items first in the two columns (e.g I want ordered alphabetically A - D)

```
<row>
   <div class="col-md">
      <item A>
      <item C>
   </div>
     <div class="col-md">
      <item B>
      <item D>
   </div>
</row>
```

so on two column screen can be seen in order A, B, C, D

But when single column it displays first column and then second column so you end up with A, C, B, D

As data goes in columns and columns must go in rows not the other way round I dont see how to solve this.

Screenshot to demonstrate the issue

[image: 2 column]

[image: 1 column]

Comment: a & c are in the same container, so when they wrap b&d are not aside but below . You need to rethink your structure and use order class too. some clues here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292954/horizontally-stacking-divs-in-same-order-with-bootstrap-grid-system-when-div-ord/59293179#59293179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boostrap might not be able to handle this, but a mix of flex and column css might help you here if every element are siblings.

here is the idea using partially bootsrtap and column CSS via custom class:

```css
div div {
  border: solid;
  /* see us */
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  break-inside: avoid;/* goes along with column-count */
}

:first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .column {
    column-count: 2
  }
  .gap-0 {
    column-gap: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p>Run snippet in full page, then resize window to see behavior while turning into columns</p>
<div class="d-md-block d-flex flex-column column gap-0">
  <div class="order-0">item A<br>line 2<br>line 3</div>
  <div class="order-2">item C<br>line 2<br>line 3</div>
  <div class="order-1"> item B<br>line 2</div>
  <div class="order-3">item D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI, thankyou that works great ! However, it requires me to go outside of standard Bootstrap and with my limited html/css skills I dont think that is something I want to do so Im just going to accept this is is a limitation of Bootstrap. (Will mark this answer as correct in a couple of days unless anyone comes up with something simpler)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need to do is that you need to define a complete row and then add the elements of the other row below that. For Eg:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            A
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            C
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            D
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will give you the desired effect.
For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Comment: This can have space over 'C' when height of 'B' is greater than height of 'A'

Comment: But each item is different size so doesnt that mean i will end up with a load of vertical gaps if say A is larger than B